# How to use WebStorm debugger with pm2

Tags: webstorm, pm2

I'm trying to specifically debug `instance1` with the WebStorm debugger. I use the WebStorm npm configuration to run the `start` script. When I just use the WebStorm `run` button, it works fine. If I use the WebStorm `debug` button, it crashes with:

> Process finished with exit code 130 (interrupted by signal 2: SIGINT)

How can I setup my local environment to be able to debug pm2 instances with WebStorm?

---

**package.json snippet**

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "HOST=$HOST_HOSTNAME pm2 start process.json --no-daemon",
},
```

---

**process.json**

```json
{
  "apps": [{
    "name": "instance1",
    "script": "src",
    "instances": 1,
    "args": "--port 3000",
    "node_args": [
      "--harmony", "--max_old_space_size=16384", "--debug=7000"
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "instance2",
    "script": "src",
    "instances": 1,
    "args": "--port 3001",
    "node_args": [
      "--harmony"
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "instance3",
    "script": "src",
    "instances": 1,
    "args": "--port 3002",
    "node_args": [
      "--harmony"
    ]
  }]
}
```

Comment: works fine for me using similar code (application started as instances 1,2 and 3 is a simple express server; Node.js version is 6.9.1). Problem must be specific to your code. Please create a support ticket, providing your idea.log and project sample

Comment: @lena -- did it work for you in debug mode? and were you able to step through your code?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what was going wrong. You need to run the client with npm, but use a javascript debugger run configuration to actually debug the code. I had to manually install the webstorm chrome plugin as well.

Instructions for creating a proper run configuration can be found here:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Starting+a+JavaScript+debug+session#StartingaJavaScriptdebugsession-Startingadebugsessionwhenusingadifferentwebserver

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/starting-the-debugger-session.html -- Link was broken. Edit queue is full.